# Report Builder - Parameter Conversion Error

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

Using Report builder and trying to "move" a dataset filter over to the dataset query in order to improve report performance.

"An error occurred while reading data from the query result set. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '70048-' to data type int."

This is my Where Statement that works (without parameter)

```
WHERE (JCCD.CostType = 1) AND JCCD.Job = '88800-'
```

This is my Where Statement that gives error after providing the parameter

```
WHERE (JCCD.CostType = 1) AND JCCD.Job = @JobParam
```

Complete SQL Statement

```
    SELECT        HQCO.Name, JCCD.JCCo, JCCD.Job, JCCD.Phase, JCJM.Description, JCJP.Description AS PhaseDescription, CAST(JCCD.EstHours AS Numeric) AS EstHours, 
                         CAST(JCCD.EstCost AS Numeric) AS EstCost, CAST(JCCD.ActualHours AS Numeric) AS ActualHours, CAST(JCCD.ActualUnits AS Numeric) AS ActualUnits, 
                         CAST(JCCD.ActualCost AS Numeric) AS ActualCost, JCCD.CostType, JCCD.UM, JCCD.CostTrans, JCCD.Mth, JCCD.JCTransType, JCJM.Job AS Expr2, JCCD.ActualDate, 
                         JCCH.UM AS UM2, CAST(JCCD.EstUnits AS Numeric) AS EstUnits, JCCD.ProjUnits, JCCH.CostType AS Expr4, JCCD.ProjHours, JCCD.ForecastHours, 
                         JCCD.ForecastUnits, JCCD.ForecastCost, CONVERT(INT,LEFT(JCCD.Phase,3)) AS PhasePreFix
FROM            JCCD AS JCCD INNER JOIN
                         JCJM AS JCJM ON JCCD.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo AND JCCD.Job = JCJM.Job INNER JOIN
                         HQCO AS HQCO ON JCCD.JCCo = HQCO.HQCo INNER JOIN
                         JCJP AS JCJP ON JCCD.JCCo = JCJP.JCCo AND JCCD.Job = JCJP.Job AND JCCD.PhaseGroup = JCJP.PhaseGroup AND JCCD.Phase = JCJP.Phase INNER JOIN
                         JCCH AS JCCH ON JCCD.JCCo = JCCH.JCCo AND JCCD.Job = JCCH.Job AND JCCD.PhaseGroup = JCCH.PhaseGroup AND JCCD.Phase = JCCH.Phase AND 
                         JCCD.CostType = JCCH.CostType
WHERE        
                         (JCCD.CostType = 1) AND (JCCD.Job = '88800-')
ORDER BY JCCD.JCCo, JCCD.Job, JCCD.Phase
```

Comment: Can you post your complete sql statement?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal I edited original post.

Comment: Is `CostType` an int? I'm guessing it is text and contains either nulls or non-numeric data.

Comment: Can you show us your declaration of the 'JobParam' parameter? My guess is you've declared that as an int, and are then trying to pass '88800-' which is a string to it.